# R - How to rename every nth column with "name_x" where x=1 and increases by 1 for each column?

Tags: r, loops, rename

I have a data set where the names of the columns are very messy, and I want to simplify them. Example data below:

```
structure(list(MemberID = 1L, This.was.the.first.question = "ABC", 
    This.was.the.first.date = 1012018L, This.was.the.first.city = "New York", 
    This.was.the.second.question = "XYZ", This.was.the.second.date = 11052018L, 
    This.was.the.second.city = "Boston"), .Names = c("MemberID", 
"This.was.the.first.question", "This.was.the.first.date", "This.was.the.first.city", 
"This.was.the.second.question", "This.was.the.second.date", "This.was.the.second.city"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

```
MemberID    This was the first question     This was the first date     This was the first city     This was the second question    This was the second date    This was the second city
1                       ABC                         1012018                    New York                 XYZ                              11052018                      Boston
```

This is what I want the columns to look like:

```
MemberID    Question_1   Date_1  City_1  Question_2  Date_2   City_2
```

So essentially the column name is the same but every 3rd column the number increases by 1. How would I do this? While this example data set small, my real data set is much larger and I want to learn how to do this by column indexing and iteration.

Comment: suppose you have n "sets", and your dataframe is called df; try n=2; colnames(df) <- c("Member ID",paste(rep(c("Question","Date"),n),rep(1:n,each=2),sep="_"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option is to remove the substring except the last word and use `make.unique`

```
names(df1)[-1] <- make.unique(sub(".*\\.", "", names(df1)[-1]), sep="_")
names(df1)
#[1] "MemberID"   "question"   "date"       "city"       "question_1" "date_1"     "city_1"
```

---

Or if we need the exact output as expected, extract the last word with `sub` and use `ave` to create the sequence based on duplicate names

```
v1 <-  sub(".*\\.(\\w)", "\\U\\1", names(df1)[-1], perl = TRUE)
names(df1)[-1] <- paste(v1, ave(v1, v1, FUN = seq_along), sep="_")
names(df1)
#[1] "MemberID"   "Question_1" "Date_1"     "City_1"  
#[5]   "Question_2" "Date_2"     "City_2"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#
# create vector of question name triplets

theList <- c("question_","date_","city_")

# create enough headings for 10 questions
questions <- rep(theList,10)

idNumbers <- 1:length(questions)

library(numbers)

# use mod function to group ids into triplets
idNumbers <- as.character(ifelse(mod(idNumbers,3)>0,floor(idNumbers/3)+1,floor(idNumbers/3)))

# concatenate question stems with numbers and add MemberID column at start of vector
questionHeaders <- c("MemberID",paste0(questions,idNumbers))
head(questionHeaders)
```

...and the output:

```
[1] "MemberID"   "question_1" "date_1"     "city_1"     "question_2" "date_2"
```

use the `colnames()` or `names()` function to assign this vector as the column names of the data frame.

As noted in the comments on the OP, the question ID numbers can be generated by using the `each=` argument in `rep()`, eliminating the need for the `mod()` function.

```
idNumbers <- rep(1:10,each = 3)
```